# Visual Studio with a Remote Server

Tags: visual-studio, remote-access

The site that I am working on is at a remote server. I want to work on it locally. Are there any tools better then that in Visual Studio for working with a remote website?

Comment: Depends on what technologies you're using on the remote site. Could you add more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deal with the quirkiness of VS remoting, what about using Remote Desktop to drive VS on a machine local to your target (behind VPN for example)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up a subversion server on the remote site you could use that to sync changes between locations. This would be really helpful in other areas as well such as allowing multiple people to mess with your code and to keep track of every change you make. It would also be the best in the area of performance.

If its a windows share, just set up the repository where it is right now then use:

svn checkout file:///project/trunk

Or if its over a web server you can set up SVN to be served though that as well.

There are plenty of free/not free plugins for VS that make working with SVN very easy.